# How to use Django Signals?

Tags: python, django

I'm practicing Signals, I have two models

models.py

```
class National_ID_Card(models.Model):
    name = *************
    ID = *************
    address = *************
    state = *************
    nation = **********

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Driving_Licence(models.Model):
    name = *************
    ID = *************
    vehicle_type = **********
    callahan   = ***********

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class NationalIDForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = National_ID_Card
        fields = ('__all__')

class DrivingLicenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Driving_Licence
        fields = ('__all__')
```

I want when i will be saving instance of `National_ID_Card` it would populate the `name` and `ID` field of `Driving_Licence` from also. I can do so with `overriding method of save` but how to do so in django signals? I tried many examples but cannt able to figure it out.

Comment: What have you tried exactly?

Comment: It looks like a bad idea to me. FIrst of all in case the two names should always be equal, then you better avoid data duplication at all, secondly, in case they don't overriding `save(..)`s, etc. is a terrible idea, since it means `.save(..)` is not idempotent anymore. Signals do the same. Typically it looks to me that the `Form` can provide "*initial*" values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a couple of ways:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def your_signal_fuction(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Your code goes here

post_save.connect(your_signal_fuction, sender=National_ID_Card)
```

Using receiver decorator

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=National_ID_Card)
def your_signal_fuction(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Your code goes here
```

Comment: Sir,why did you import User?

Comment: I did it inadvertently. Edited it.

Comment: sir, i cant figure out what to write with in those syntax !

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak This will help you to understand signal better. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html